# Getting all values from a Tablix row in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

An SSRS tablix displays data as shown below.
The tablix gets its data from a Stored procedure.
Each amount that is displayed in the tablix is the sum of many 'Account' values.

what I am trying to achieve is as follows ...
When the cell containing 1000 is clicked, I want to get all the 'Account' values that make up that 1000 and pass it as a parameter to another report.
However, right now, it is only passing the first 'Account'.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Usually, instead of passing all the records IDs, I would pass the criteria to identify them - CAT= **Nursing**  & Row= **DON+Salaries** & MONTH= **Jan** for the ACTION and use a similar query for the drill through report as you're using for the main report.

Comment: @Hannover - Thanks for the suggestion.... Yes. I think thats the only way to get this done.